# Simple linear equation $\frac{2}{4x-7} = \frac{10}{9x-4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the linear equation:

$$\frac{2}{4x-7} = \frac{10}{9x-4}$$

The answer I get is $\frac{31}{11}$.

Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean $$\frac{2}{4x-7} = \frac{10}{9x-4}$$ yes, it is.

Comment: It's easy to check solutions of equations: plug your solution back in and see if everything matches.

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to $$18x-8=40x-70\iff 22x=62\iff x=\dfrac{31}{11}$$

Comment: Note, though, that since the original equation contains fractions, you must check that your solution does not make either denominator zero (it doesn't).